# Using a class to print items of a list which the item is a list, looking like an array when printed

Tags: python, class, matrix, arraylist, printing

So I know the description of the title is kinda confusing, but hopefully explaining it with pictures is probably more understanding. So basicly I have a class called 'Matrix':

[image: Code]

So when I call the method set_matrix in the class Matrix, the following code should return m1 as:

[image: Output]

I've already done it with the numbers seperated with commas, but I dont know to do it with numbers
seperated with spaces inside the list :/. Any help would be well appreciated :)

This is following code with the items of each list seperated with commas:

```
class Matrix:

def __init__(self):

    self.__list = []

def set_matrix(self, matrix_list):

    self.__list.append(matrix_list)

def __str__(self):

    output_string = ''

    for i in self.__list:

        for j in i:
            
            output_string += str(j) + '\n'

    return output_string

m1 = Matrix()

m1.set_matrix( [[1,2,3,4],[5,6,7,8],[9,8,7,6]] )
print('m1:')
print(m1)
```

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution:

```
class Matrix:

def __init__(self):

    self.__list = []

def set_matrix(self, matrix_list):

    self.__list.append(matrix_list)

def __str__(self):

    output_string = ''

    for i in self.__list:

        for j in i:
            
            output_string += str(j).replace(',', '').replace('[', '[ ').replace(']', ' ]') + '\n'

    return output_string

m1 = Matrix()

m1.set_matrix( [[1,2,3,4],[5,6,7,8],[9,8,7,6]] )
print('m1:')
print(m1)
```